# XML Exception while Parsing from String to DOM error

Tags: java, xml, matlab, dom

In my code, I am converting DOM object to String object and replace few strings and again writing to DOM object.

While doing so, am traversing many files, code works first time while for 2nd file, while writing to DOM object , java exception thrown.

I know root cause, as two root element for xml has getting generated , however don't have idea to eliminate

```
Java exception occurred: 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
```

```
@ Code
doc = docBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
TramsformerObj.transform(DOMSource(doc),StreamResult(writerObj));

% Replace String
try
StrObj = writerObj.getBuffer.toString.replaceAll(Sourcestr,Replacestr);
catch ME
    disp(ME.message)
end

% Convert String to DOM object
try
    isObj.setCharacterStream(java.io.StringReader(StrObj));
    docm = docBuilder.parse(isObj);
catch ME
    disp(ME.message)
end
```

PS:- Note all object/ variables are available in memory and accesible. This code is of MATLAB, am invoking all packages of JAVA in MATLAB

Comment: I guess you'll have to show some code, start with the loop over those "many files" and how you marshal from the String to a DOM tree.

Comment: Looks like your xml is not correct. please add it.

Comment: @ laune and Jens :- Edited question with Code Part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the LSinput isObj (if that's what it is) should be recreated for each
new file before you set the character stream and pass the isObj to the parse method.
Also, recreate the LSParser docBuilder

```
isObj = new InputSource
docm = DOMImplementationLS.createLSParser(...);

isObj.setCharacterStream(java.io.StringReader(StrObj));
docm = docBuilder.parse(isObj);
```

Comment: isObj is instance of org.xml.sax isObj = org.xml.sax.InputSource();

Comment: All right, same thing - recreate for each file to avoid keeping some remains from the previous file. (It wouldn't hurt to write this all in Java and translate the tested version to MATLAB.)

Comment: Hello Laune, it was great help from you for current questionaire. I have faced other Java exception error for some other task . can it be possible for you to provide answer for  [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487976/exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-nullpointerexception-for-matl

Comment: @IntelK I've had a look at it, but without source or javadoc for com.mathworks.mde.cmdwin.CmdWin it's hopeless. Also, I guess the code leading up to `java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()` might be useful for determining the cause. Looks as if something is null that should be around for making the Command Window happy.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer to this is using XML within XML will break you need to not parse the inner XML and use the CDATA tag see here:[Check This](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
  <sometag></sometag>
  <![CDATA[
    <?xml version='1.0'?>
    <nonParsedTag></nonParsedTag>
  ]]>
```